# sharing a instance of class between components

Tags: java, spring, filter, autowired

So I have a spring boot application.
I created a filter that fetches JWT token from requests. Then (in same filter class) I make a request to another service (using http get with JWT) and I'd like to save data to autowired class.

then in controller class I'd like to access that data.
I found a solution using threadlocal and using request scope.
But I think the most elegant and the most spring way of doing thnings is the following:

**Model class:**

```
@Component
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode= ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class AuthManagementUser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private AuthManagementOrgs[] organizations;
```

**Filter class:**

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplateInterceptor token;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    AuthManagementUser amUser;



    // filter for catching authorization token before processing request and saving
    // it in a scope request in case of request from this microservice
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("authorization") != null){
            token.setToken(((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("authorization"));
            this.amUser = userService.retrieveUserDataAuthManagementMock();
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

**Controller class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "user", name = "User")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    LdapUserRepository ldapUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    AuthManagementUser amUser;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ArrayList<LdapUserModel> User()
    { 
        return this.userService.checkCreate(this.amUser);
    }
```

So as you see, I'd like to make AuthManagementUser class singleton(?) and make it available to controller (if filter fails the user cannot get to the controller, so I can assume that AuthManagementUser will always have data). But currently when I am inside controller the AuthManagementUser object is null...

Thanks for help!

Comment: On this line... `this.amUser = userService.retrieveUserDataAuthManagementMock();` ...you're replacing a reference, you don't modify the original value. Is the original value `null`?

Comment: hmm not sure if I understand this :(  
When I'm debugging filter the `userService.retrieveUserDataAuthManagementMock()` returns an object not null

Comment: when you assign reference in the filter it doesn't affect reference in the controller. Because these are two independent references.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for clarification. Any tips on fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by mixing `@Scope` with `@Autowire` . All fields annotated with `@Autowire` are filled after construction of the corresponding bean, so it's a one-time thing. In your case, you want to replace the bean per request which is not what `@Autowired` is meant for (TBOMK).

When working with `@Scope`, give `@Resource` a try (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) .

Alternatively, you can store the class in `ThreadLocal` .